# Processor Expert eclipse-based plug-in error on Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I installed the plugin according to freescale install instructions in http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=PE_DRIVER_SUITE&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab# but after the installation, it raise an error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: “Open last Processor Expert project”.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And in the log file:

```
!ENTRY com.freescale.processorexpert.core 4 0 2013-09-07 01:45:19.428
!MESSAGE reg.getExtensionPoint is empty

!ENTRY com.freescale.processorexpert.core 4 0 2013-09-07 01:45:19.531
!MESSAGE No com.freescale.processorexpert.core.PEservice extension found!

!ENTRY com.processorexpert.core.ide.wizard.ui 2 0 2013-09-07 01:45:29.810
!MESSAGE External elements location /Applications/eclipse/ProcessorExpert/Config/PE/CPE/wizard_data/wizards/components does not exist
```

Any tips on what might be happening? This same plugin works perfectly on linux machines with the same version of eclipse(kepler).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Freescale's Processor Export (PEx) Eclipse plug-in is not supported on Mac OS X.

https://community.freescale.com/message/367027#367027

How/why they took a cross-platform development environment like Eclipse and wrote a tool for it that is not cross-platform is beyond me.